# Setup for Microsoft Teams Menus Module SDK is failing. setNavBarMenu() is not displaying the item in the navigation bar

Tags: sdk, navigation, microsoft-teams

Thanks for taking the time to review this matter.

So I've been going through this issue for a couple of days now. I'm trying to set up a navigation menu on my Microsoft Teams Side App. A set of personal tabs is exactly what it is. Following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/personal-apps?view=msteams-client-js-1.12.1#use-a-personal-app-private-workspace

It explicitly shows how we can add a navigation bar at the top-right of our application:

[Screenshot from MSTeams documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2bg9.png)

Simple, right?

Well, it doesn't seem to work like that. When I try and follow the SDK instructions to set the navigation bar using the function microsoftTeams.menus.setNavBarMenu() it doesn't display anything nor provide any sort of error message on the console

This is the code I have set up for my Angular component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core"
import {app, menus, pages} from "@microsoft/teams-js"
import {Location} from '@angular/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './my-app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-app.scss'],
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {
  public initialized = false
  public theme = 'default'

  constructor(private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    app.initialize().then((response) => {
      this.initialized = true

      app.getContext().then((context) => {
        if (context.app.theme !== 'default') {
          this.theme = 'dark'
        }
      })

      app.registerOnThemeChangeHandler((theme: string) => {
        if (theme !== 'default') {
          this.theme = 'dark'
        } else {
          this.theme = 'default'
        }
      })

      pages.backStack.registerBackButtonHandler(() => {
        this.location.back()

        return true
      })

      menus.initialize()

      const item = new menus.MenuItem()

      item.id = 'test'
      item.icon = 'there is an <svg></svg> tag here but I shortened it for easier reading'
      item.title = 'test'
      item.displayMode = menus.DisplayMode.ifRoom

      console.log(item)

      menus.setNavBarMenu([item], (id) => {
        console.log(id)

        return true
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Nothing fancy. Just an HTML template with some styling that you can ignore. This is just a mock testing app. The only difference is that I import the namespace directly.

So, everything else is working: Microsoft Teams is being initialized, the theme handler sets a default or dark theme, and the back button works as indicated. The only thing that's missing is the navBarMenu.

I tried with and without an Icon value inside the string, with and without the displayMode property, I tried it directly on the HTML parent using a script tag, tried the previous SDK version (1.16) and this one (2.5)

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something on this setup, but I can't seem to find any information regarding this SDK menus module and the documentaion isn't really helpful there (Or maybe I'm not smart enough to get it, yet)

Again, thank you so much for reading me. Any feedback on anything I'm doing wrong or could potentially improve is completly welcome

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are trying this in mobile client? Please note that this API is not supported in web/Desktop client.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I didn't know about that. Interesting. Do you know how to try a development package in a mobile client?

Comment: You can upload and install the app in Teams desktop or web client. Login with the same user or any user from same tenant in Teams mobile app. 
User now can start using the above uploaded app in Teams mobile.

Comment: I'll check on that @Meghana-MSFT. Thanks for your input